# Observing controller property from view only works if get('controller') called from didInsertElement

Tags: ember.js

Note the below Ember view definition. If I remove the `didInsertElement` call or comment out the `get('controller')` call, the `setupMultiselect` observer never gets called. Is this a feature or a bug? Confused...

```
Discourse.KbRelatedObjView = Discourse.View.extend({

  ...

  didInsertElement: function() { var self = this;
    // for some reason this needs to be here else the observer below never fires
    self.get('controller');
  },

  setupMultiselect: function() { var self = this;

    ...

  }.observes('controller.objPage')

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's a feature or a bug, more like a quirk. It is the expected behavior though. It's noted [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html).

> UNCONSUMED COMPUTED PROPERTIES DO NOT TRIGGER OBSERVERS
>
> If you never get a computed property, its observers will not fire even if its dependent keys change. You can think of the value changing from one unknown value to another.
>
> This doesn't usually affect application code because computed properties are almost always observed at the same time as they are fetched. For example, you get the value of a computed property, put it in DOM (or draw it with D3), and then observe it so you can update the DOM once the property changes.
>
> If you need to observe a computed property but aren't currently retrieving it, just get it in your init method.